# Load regulation and battery charging

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, battery-operated

With the [MCP73871](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002090C.pdf), the load regulation is 0.08%. Does that mean it expects the battery voltage to increase strictly monotonically? That is, if the device consumes 2000mA at 5V (around 3000mA at 3.7V) from the battery, the MCP73871 will simply shut off entirely, making the load consume solely from the battery and the battery not draw current from the MCP73871 at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load regulation specification tells you something about how much Vbat changes over different output currents when the battery is charged and the unit is powered from an external voltage. It is maximum 0.18 % (0.08 % typical) of for example 4.2 V = 7.6 mV (max)
 ===> I would not worry about it :-)

No the chip does not expect the battery voltage to increase monotonically while charging. It does not have to. Typical charging mode for Li based cells is current limited when Vbat is below a certain voltage, Voltage limiting above this voltage and charge to a specified voltage. This is exactly what the MCP73871 does.

2000mA is on (maybe over) the edge of what this chip is designed for. The MCP73871 will not shut off I think as it will have to keep the internal switch closed. But it will not drain the battery much, so you can assume it uses no power. This is what it is designed to do :-)

Comment: Oh right. Regarding shut off, I'm trying to have a grasp on the 'Chip Behavior Reference Table'. I'm not sure if it suggests that when the load tries to draw, e.g., 2000mA, the MCP will not charge the battery and feed all current (1.8A) to the load. Is my reading correct?

Comment: If there's no external power connected, so Vin < Vbat then you get state 2 and the battery will be connected via the 200 mohms switch to Vout and the battery will supply the 2000 mA. In case where there is external power you can configure what happens. See states 7,8 and 9 and the CE (Charge Enable) input. If enough input power is present both external power and battery power can be used for the load or not, depending on how you configure the chip.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly, at state 9 (CE = high), when the load draws 2000mA, the MCP can only supply 1.8A since 1.8A is shared between the load and the battery - correct? If so, would this be hazardous given that the load draws more than what the MCP can supply?

Comment: I think that is indeed how state 9 works. I do not think anything will break if the load would draw more current than 2000 mA. Worst case the chip will get too hot and shut itself down (Thermal shutdown).